# Escape octal value in javascript string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, escaping, octal

I'm using Google Apps Script to add some functionality to Google Sheets. My functionality imports data from BigQuery using a query I've been using successfully within the BigQuery UI.

Part of the query does a regex replace on a value - the syntax for the replacement is `//1`, `//2`, etc.

```
var request = {
    useLegacySql: false,
    query: "SELECT LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(Web_MktSrc, r\"(\w*)\W+(\w*)\", \"\\1\\2\")) AS Web_MktSrc, WebFormCampaign, COUNT(1) AS NumRows FROM `output_dataset` GROUP BY 1, 2;"
};
```

(note that the above script scrolls off-screen)

My script is failing with the message:

```
Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: Octal escape must be followed by 3 octal digits but saw: \1\2 at [1:57]
```

I think this is at the `\\1\\2` point, but I've tried escaping the `\` within the regex match string too and can't get past this error.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Just a guess but you are putting escaped regex inside of a string so the escapes are counting for the string, not the regex. You probably need to double escape them (`\\\`)

Comment: Thanks @Marie. If I understand what you mean, I've tried that with `r\"(\\w*)\\W+(\\w*)\"`

Comment: Consider using `String.fromCharCode` to create the string \ values.